# UserManager CheckPassword() rehash the password in .net core 3.1 and can't sign in from asp.net MVC Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using asp.net Identity for signing in users in **asp.net MVC** Project and It's working fine.
I've created new **.net core 3.1 API** project and used the **Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core** for checking usernames and passwords to generate tokens.

The problem is that the .net core project rehashes the password and I'm not able to login from the old asp.net MVC project

This is my code:

```
var user = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserName == UserName);

bool result = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword()` method to verify the user current hashed password and avoid rehashing and it works successfully.

My Code:

```
var verigyResult = _userManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, password);

if (verigyResult != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed) // either verigyResult equal to SuccessRehashNeeded or Success
{
    //handle success login...
}
else
{
    //handle invalid login credentials...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your old application hashed using options `PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2`and when you migrated to new application the default is `PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV3` and when you have password hashed with IdentityV2 and then you start using IdentityV3, ASP.NET identity rehashes it by default ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/afed08f425e7b034f231d411c9dfb4f46de8bc9c/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L710)). You should use `PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2` in new app also, something like:

`services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(o => o.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);`

Comment: Thanks @41D0 for your answer. I think this will work but I've already used `PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword()` method to avoid rehashing and still on `IdentityV3`

Comment: This is the best solution.
If you also need to implement a change password and password reset feature on the new app without updating the old project. These features need to rehash the password. Then the accepted solution will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too but I've searched a lot about it. when password come from view to controller you use `CreateAsync(model.username, model.password)` and this method change the **real password** to **hash password** and you can't use it by yourself expect of using in action methods that have real password param in their input. forexample the code below give a string from user. check it by `UserManager.FindAsync()` and put it in some variable.

```
 public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
      var findUser = UserManager.FindAsync(email, password);
    }
```

and in your example you can take input and check:

```
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
      var IsUserExist = UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(email, password);
    }
```